# OpenCV assertion error with sliced video frame

Tags: python, opencv, assertion

I am trying to slice a video capture frame for image data collection of hand gestures, so I thought an easy place to start would be to slice a video frame and write the frames from a specific part of the frame to a directory, but I am having this constant assertion error when I try to so much as show the sliced frame. I've searched for other solutions, but I can't figure it out

The code is

```
    import numpy as np
    t,r,b,l = 250, 500, 500,50
    fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while cam.isOpened():
        ret,frame = cam.read()
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(l,t),(r,b),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        (h,w) = frame.shape[:2]
        roi = frame[t:b,r:l]
        cv2.imshow('roi',roi) #giving error
        if 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
   cam.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've also tried:
`cv2.imshow('roi',roi.astype('uint8')`
and
`cv2.imshow('roi',np.asarray(roi,dtype='uint8'))`
All are giving me the same error

I keep getting this error:
error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Edit: `roi =frame[t:b,r:l]`
keeps returning an empty list, how can i slice the ndarray frame so that I get a proper sliced array?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Looks like your frame is empty...

Comment: that's odd. Cause the frame is showing just fine, but maybe its an issue with the frame slicing?
Yeah, I tried printing roi and its just an empty list

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue was entirely about the way it was being sliced:

my code was:
`roi = frame[t:b, r:l]` where the slice should be [rows, columns]
My mistake was slicing the columns right to left, instead of left to right.
`roi = frame[t:b, l:r]` gives the sliced frame as desired